# Connecting to MySQL database hosted on CPanel

Tags: web-crawlers, cpanel, mysql

I have followed all of the usual steps in setting up a pipeline but cannot seem to get the database itself to connect. I am confident in the correct database name, username passowrd etc but am confused as to whether to use 'localhost' or the domain name I see when viewing the database as the host name.

Below is the pipeline class:

```
class MySqlPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'uwpsnapshot_user',
            port = '3306',
            password = 'password',
            database = 'uwpsnapshot_scrapy_data',
        )

        # Create cursor, used to exectue SQL statements


        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        # Clear old data from table
        self.cur.execute(""" truncate table my_crawler """)
        self.conn.commit()
```

And a screenshots of the database interface on phpmyadmin:
[phpmyadmin database interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVlqp.png)

In the browser the domain appears as `chost5.is.ed.ac.uk` with the port as `2083`. When I try to connect with these parameters the script runs for roughly 30 secs (I assume trying to find a connection) and then returns a connection error. The same happens with port `3306`.

The error message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 296, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

When I use the `localhost` host name the script instantly returns the same connection error with no buffer period. In my mind this means the host name is more likely to be `chost5.is.ed.ac.uk` but I am not confident in this.

The error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 296, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61)
```

The database itself I created using CPanel and also used this interface to configure the user, making sure to give the user all privelages. Below is a screenshot of the database interface on cpanel.
[cpanel database title card with privelaged user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCeYb.png)

This clearly shows that the privelaged user is correct in the configuration.

I have connected to SQL databases before but have not had this trouble and am especially new to cpanel.

I have added my IP to the *Remote MySql* section on CPanel (i.e. as an as an *Access Host*) but this has not resolved the issue.

Comment: If your database is in the same machine, try changing *localhost* to *127.0.0.1*. You can also try to troubleshoot by connecting locally via SSH to your MySQL server and see if you can access the DB directly. If the server is remote, you have to allow remote connections in the MySQL configuration, check firewalls, etc.